# Gitlab CI with Grails3/Gradle inject tag name into war file

Tags: tomcat, gradle, gitlab-ci, grails3

We need to inject the release git tag used to trigger the build in Gitlab into the war file so it can be read by the tomcat server and used as output for an action.

AFAIR this worked with old versions of Grails. 
Anyone any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found it to be pretty straight forward using bash commands in Gitlab CI:

Inside the ci file `.gitlab-ci.yml` put:

```
before_script:
   - mkdir -p files
   - echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME > files/version.txt
   - echo "war {" >> build.gradle
   - echo "   from('files') {" >> build.gradle
   - echo "      include 'version.txt'" >> build.gradle
   - echo "      into('files')" >> build.gradle
   - echo "   }" >> build.gradle
   - echo "}" >> build.gradle
```

This version file is now accessible as

new File('files', 'version.txt') in your application.